# get v-select text on select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-select

I saw some documentation on v-select and slots, but didn't really understand if I can apply it for my example [codepen](https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/ExjMMGz?editors=1010).

I just need to get the selected **text** (not the value), and use it somewhere in the code:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    state: {},
    selectedText: "",
    states: [
      { value: "a", text: "alpha" },
      { value: "b", text: "beta" },
      { value: "g", text: "gamma" }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    change: (newValue) => {
      // do something with the text
      // "alpha", "beta", or "gama"
      console.log(newValue);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.20/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.20/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <label>my selected text is: {{state}}</label>
      <v-row align="center">
        <v-col cols="3">
          <v-select v-model="state" :items="states" @change="change" :text="selectedText"></v-select>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `this.state.text` to access the selected value.

Comment: @Aside not correct, {{state}} changes to "a", "b" keys

Comment: Are you using the `vue-select` or the `vue-search-select` module?

Comment: @Aside you have the code pen, and you have the code here, I don't understand the question

Comment: You use `state.text` in the codepen to display the selected text property and it works. In the code above you use `state` instead of `state.text`. But as seen in the codepen `this.state.text` clearly returns the selected text value. Just don't pass it as an argument for `@change` and use the data property instead.

Comment: I explained more clearly my problems with this approach in my answer. could you take a look? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `return-object` prop to `<v-select>`

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    state: null,
    selectedText: "",
    states: [
      { value: "a", text: "alpha" },
      { value: "b", text: "beta" },
      { value: "g", text: "gamma" }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    change: (newValue) => {
      // do something with the text
      // "alpha", "beta", or "gama"
      console.log(newValue.text);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.20/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.20/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <label>my selected text is: {{state && state.text}}</label>
      <v-row align="center">
        <v-col cols="3">
          <v-select :items="states" v-model="state" @change="change" item-text="text" return-object></v-select>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**Edit:**
Ok so based on your approach, the solution would be to use the country code to find appropriate country object in the country list and set that.

Here is how you would solve it:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    country: "c",
    countries: [{
        code: "a",
        name: "Ameriga Fatela"
      },
      {
        code: "b",
        name: "Bolivia Grande"
      },
      {
        code: "c",
        name: "Comore Potentia"
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    getCountryCode() {
      return "b"; // have no c.name here!
    },
    change() {
      var newCode = this.getCountryCode();
      // Since we were getting objects when changing options, we must also set objects 
      this.country = this.countries.filter(country => country.code === newCode)[0];
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.20/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.20/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <div>current code is &gt;{{country.code}}&lt;</div>
      <div>current name is &gt;{{country.name}}&lt;</div>
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12">
          <v-select v-model="country" :items="countries" item-text="name" item-value="code" return-object></v-select>
          <v-btn @click="change">change by script to 'b'</v-btn>
          </vcol>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to return object, I want only to recuperate the selected text on change

Comment: Ok, so I edited to get the selected text (should be easy once you have the object)

Comment: is there a way to recuperate the text without returning the object, cause I want to keep using the code for other things

Comment: I'm not aware of a method to return text only. Honestly I don't understand the problem with receiving an object and using one of its fields.

Comment: I already pluged the logic and all my modifications takes the code when the select changes. Now, only for a function I need the text, I will not broke all my previous logic. I only need to get the selected text for an event

Comment: Is it not possible for you to use `state.text` for the function?

Comment: "state" actually is not an object, but a string, and it is used in a lot of places. I would like to keep it string

Comment: Well seeing your reluctance to make any JS changes, I would advise you to switch the variable names in your original array. Make it `{ value: "alpha", text: "a" }` and use the code in your question

Comment: i explained more clearly my problems with this approach in my answer. could you take a look? thanks.

Comment: @Serge I've edited my answer, hopefully should be clearer for you to understand now

Comment: even if now I am forced to search each time the code changes the country name, before it wasn't the need.... I think the actual code can be optimised ....

Comment: because I already filled-in  the control with the country code and name, now, each time I change the value i should re-search the name...

Comment: Yes for this very purpose I had suggested my initial solution where the object was already in `state`

Comment: by the way, i obsrerved there is no need to fill-in the name of the coutnry, the only code is enought to change the combobox

Comment: propably I just need to change the code, and then generate some "changed" event on the box, in order the box puts the complete value in the object

Comment: I found a lighter option just using a computed property to find the countryName, and do not return object (see my edited answer). However, in both cases we should recalculate the country name. That is not good. Imagine to build the combobox we have to do a heavy operation... recalculating it each time is time-consuming and really not optimal....

Answer (score 0):

Your `states` objects contain both `value` and `text` properties. If you change `value` to `key` v-select recognizes the change and you can access the `text` property via `this.state`. Like so:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    state: {},
    selectedText: "",
    states: [
      { key: "a", text: "alpha" },
      { key: "b", text: "beta" },
      { key: "g", text: "gamma" }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    change: (newValue) => {
      // do something with the text
      // "alpha", "beta", or "gama"
      console.log(newValue); // Also returns text attribute instead of key
    }
  }
});
```

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <label>my selected text is: {{state}}</label>
      <v-row align="center">
        <v-col cols="3">
          <v-select v-model="state" :items="states" @change="change"></v-select>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: I explained more clearly my problems with this approach in my answer. could you take a look? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** 
The best option I found is to use a **`computed`** property for the selected text, without changes to the current code (go in *FullPage* after lauching the snippet to correctly see the output):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    countries: [
      { code: "a", name: "Ameriga Fatela" },
      { code: "b", name: "Bolivia Grande" },
      { code: "c", name: "Comore Potentia" }
    ],
    country: "b"
  },
  methods: {
    getCountryCode() {
      return "c"; // have no c.name here!
    },
    change() {
      this.country = this.getCountryCode();
    }
  },
  computed: {
    countryName() {
      return this.countries.find((c) => c.code === this.country).name;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.20/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.20/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <div>current code is &gt;{{country}}&lt;</div>
      <div>current name is &gt;{{countryName}}&lt;</div>
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12">
          <v-select v-model="country" :items="countries" item-text="name" item-value="code"></v-select>
          <v-btn @click="change">change by script to '{{getCountryCode()}}'</v-btn>
          </vcol>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Another option is ([Codepen here](https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/ExjMMGz?editors=1010)) the suggestion of Anurag Srivastava to use `return-object`, I returned the object. However, it have some drawbacks, cause actually I am not able to properly change the value by code:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    country: "c",
    countries: [
      { code: "a", name: "Ameriga Fatela" },
      { code: "b", name: "Bolivia Grande" },
      { code: "c", name: "Comore Potentia" }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    getCountryCode() {
      return "b"; // have no c.name here!
    },
    change() {
      var newCode = this.getCountryCode();
      this.country = newCode;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.20/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.20/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <div>current code is &gt;{{country.code}}&lt;</div>
      <div>current name is &gt;{{country.name}}&lt;</div>
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12">
          <v-select v-model="country" :items="countries" item-text="name" item-value="code" return-object></v-select>
          <v-btn @click="change">change by script to 'b'</v-btn>
          </vcol>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

However, in both cases we should recalculate the country name. That is not good. Imagine to build the combobox we have to do a heavy operation... recalculating it each time is time-consuming and really not optimal....